# How can I change the time zone of bandwidthd?

Tags: indicator, bandwidth

Is there any way to change the UTC offset for the graphs generated by [bandwidthd](http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 5):

The [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bandwidthd/files/) does use and store timestamps, that are then provided to the C functions *ctime()* and *localtime()* in order to display the date at the top of the page, and at the bottom of the graphs.

These Unix timestamps are time-zone-less, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.
To get a human readable time, *ctime()* and *localtime()* automatically adjust the time zone to be used according to your system time zone (via a call to *tzset()*).

**Forcing the TZ the time of a command**

You can force anyway the time zone to a given value just for the time of a command execution, or during a whole daemon session, like *bandwidthd*. The environment variable `TZ` is read by *tzset()* to adjust the timezone, if set.

First have a look at the time zone definitions in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`

Then for instance, `cd` to your home dir in a terminal, and do a simple `ls -lrt` to see the most recent files at the bottom of the list. Then set the timezone to Paris, France, for instance

```
export TZ="Europe/Paris"
```

and do another `ls -lrt`, the time should be different (if you happen to have a system configured with a timezone set to France you may want to choose another TZ!).

Now unset the TZ var, just to prevent some mistakes based on time displayed in the terminal.

```
unset TZ
```

**Changing the TZ of *bandwidthd***

I assume you installed the *bandwidthd* package from Ubuntu `apt-get`, and you should have an init file for it to start as a service. Do a copy somewhere of the file and then edit it as root (*vi* or another editor)

```
sudo cp -p /etc/init.d/bandwidthd ~/bandwidthd.save
sudo vi /etc/init.d/bandwidthd
```

Near the top you see a few variables definitions

```
NAME=bandwidthd
DESC=BandwidthD
...
```

add one (eg, for Paris)

```
MYTZ="Europe/Paris"
```

then, further below in the *startd()* function, you should see

```
    cd $WORKDIR && start-stop-daemon --start --quiet \
            --pidfile $PIDFILE \
            --chdir $WORKDIR \
            --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
```

change it to

```
    cd $WORKDIR && start-stop-daemon --start --quiet \
            --pidfile $PIDFILE \
            --chdir $WORKDIR \
            --exec /usr/bin/env TZ="$MYTZ" $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
```

(notice the `/usr/bin/env TZ="$MYTZ"` between `--exec` and `$DAEMON`).

**Restart the process**

```
sudo service bandwidthd restart
```

and, could take a few seconds, the files should be updated, in a browser open `file:///var/lib/bandwidthd/htdocs/index.html` (or the dir where the files are written) to check.